# CRITICAL_SECTION in auto_ptr and no DeleteCriticalSection call

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, c++builder, critical-section

I have in front of me some code that I'm not quite sure I think is ok.
A critical section is put into a `auto_ptr` and `DeleteCriticalSection` is never called on it. But I seem to remember that instances of `CRITICAL_SECTION` should only be modified with the critical section functions. I tried running this through a memory leak check and it complained.

This is of course part of a multi threaded system and access to the critical section is done in several places. But if I trim it down this is basically how the `CRTITCAL_SECTION`is treated now.

```
void test() {
  auto_ptr<CRITICAL_SECTION> foo;
  foo.reset(new CRITICAL_SECTION());
  InitializeCriticalSection(foo.get()); 
}
```

Since I don't belive the `auto_ptr` going out of scope correctly delets the critical section I tried to quickly change this to

```
void test() {
  auto_ptr<CRITICAL_SECTION> foo;
  foo.reset(new CRITICAL_SECTION());
  InitializeCriticalSection(foo.get()); 
  DeleteCriticalSection(foo.get());
}
```

and the memory leak detection became much happier.
The critical sections exists until the application shut down. So should I take the time to update the code to use `DeleteCriticalSection` to actually delete the critical section, or just live with the fact that the application shuts down and releases all memory anyway?

**Update**

Answer to *WhozCraig*: Yes, looking at it several instances of objects containing a critical section can be alive at any given time and can't share a single global critical section.

Comment: Why is the `CRITICAL_SECTION` being `new`ed in the first place? Typically it'd just be a global variable or a member of some class that was responsible for the multithreaded stuff.

Comment: I agree, I just just wanted to write down how they have done it and not clean it up in anyway.

Comment: I concur with Praetorian. There is no presented reason for this to be dynamically allocated. Is there, perchance, one of these buried in each *object* of a specific class and each is responsible for latching down concurrent access to the objects on a per-object basis?

Comment: Why are you expecting `auto_ptr` to know about critical section cleanup rules? Auto_ptr is known to call `delete` on stored pointers which calls the destructor on stored objects; CRITICAL_SECTION is a C-compliant structure that does not have a destructor.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, there could be multiple instances of objects containing critical sections.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: I don't, that's the entire point. I didn't write this, I saw it when opening a file at work and was like "... ehhh... wait a second"

Comment: @inquam that was what I somewhat figured based on the presentation. In that case a single CRTIICAL_SECTION wrapped in an construct-initializer (or just in your objects constructor) should suffice. I see no need for dynamic allocation of the CS. Your object holding it is likely already dynamically allocated.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yea, that's my idea to re-write it as. And have `DeleteCriticalSection`beeing called in the objects destructor.

Comment: @inquam Prety much. there is ONE reason for doing this that I just thought of: If the object itself contains shallow pointers to other resources and accessing *those* are also being protected by the CS, then the dynamic critical section is potentially being shared across those shallow copies of that object on purpose. If that is the case, (and if so, the original author should be throttled with a cane), it may not be as trivial as it first seems. Read your presented code carefully and see if that might be the reason.